# How do to change an array of hosts gsettings using ansible?

Tags: linux, shell, gnome, ansible

I want to disable the maximzing feature on gnome on the gsettings. I have used this command shell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides edge-tiling false
```

But this per user setting.

I have tried this playbook but this only affects only my user settings. How could I change the gsettings of all users to disable maximizing.

I probably am approaching it the wrong way, instead of trying to edit the user gsettings, is there a way to edit the file that has all user settings?

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: disable auto maximize
      become_user: 'joe'
      shell: gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides edge-tiling false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried and tested but it is using the dconf.  In my case created a template to source from then write to /etc/dconf folder.   You have to dconf update afterwards (or after your task runs). You can use the dconf-editor (yum installed) to see the variable changed or manually change it without gsettings, GUI interface.

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: disable auto maximize
      template: 
        src: edit-dconf-settings
        path: /etc/dconf
    - name: update dconf
      shell: dconf update
```

template: edit-dconf-settings

```
[org/gnome/shell/extensions/classic-overrides]
edge-tiling=false
```

Answer (score 4):

There is now (ansible >= 2.4) [a native dconf module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/dconf_module.html) allowing to modify dconf settings.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: disable auto maximize
      dconf:
        key: "org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides"
        value: "['edge-tiling', 'false']"
```

Comment: `gsettings` deprecated and replaces `gconf`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [community module](https://github.com/jistr/ansible-gsetting), similar to the `gconf` (which is deprecated).

From the project's README:

```yml
- name: do not remember mount password
  gsetting:
    user: jistr
    settings:
      org.gnome.shell.remember-mount-password: false
      org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.panel-main-menu: "@as []"
      org.gnome.nautilus.preferences.default-folder-viewer: "'list-view'"
```